# Navigation Bar Title Not Displaying On Storyboard Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

### Xcode 9

I've tried to change the text color for the Navigation Item's title, but I've had no luck. It doesn't display at the Storyboard either at the running app.

These are the properties I've tried to change, but titles aren't displaying at the View Controllers.

[image: nav properties]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was embedding the view into a tab controller after the navigation controller. I invert the order (that's the right way tab->nav->view) and now title is displaying.